# Deploy a sharepoint designer workflow to prod

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I got already my sp workflow running on dev, is there anyway to export it to wsp and import it and install it with powershell?

I dont have sharepoint designer on productions.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this is still causing grief, there is a way to migrate SharePoint Designer list workflows from one location to another. The approach is fairly manual but is a useful alternative to other options.

1. Using SharePoint Designer, select the workflow and `Export to Visio`. This creates a `.vwi` file which is just a zip file.
2. Add the `.zip` suffix to the filename.
3. At the new location, create a new workflow with the same name and publish it. This will create the necessary boilerplate for the workflow.
4. Now select the new workflow, `Export to Visio`, and add the `.zip` suffix to the new workflow's filename.
5. Extract the file `Workflow.xoml.wfconfig.xml` from the new `.zip` file.
6. Replace the same file in the original `.zip`.
7. Remove the `.zip` extension from original and `Import from Visio` to import the workflow.

If the workflow accesses other lists then the list id GUIDs can be updated in the `workflow.xoml` file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article covering methods to do this. Generally I have found the most convenient way to deploy designer based workflows is just to use designer to deploy them (you don't need it installed on the production server). 
The basic methodology is

1. Creat the VS Workflow Project
2. Copy the .xoml and .rules files into
   the VS project.
3. Deploy and debug the workflow.

[Porting SharePoint Designer Workflows to Visual Studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2007/07/06/porting-sharepoint-designer-workflows-to-visual-studio.aspx)

Comment: I think it is not good to install VS on production environment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275037/is-it-safe-and-acceptable-to-install-vs-net-on-your-production-server

Comment: I agree. That's why I said you don't need to install it on the server.